# passing a parameter to a service using ngclick AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

Hey I have array of numbers, I am writing them using ng-repeat. When you click on some number should be pass to function **passParameterToService** parameter index and should be saved in service to variable this.whichBoard. But I have do something wrong, can someone tell me why ng-repeat don't work when I add service and why after click on some number, it's dont write to a variable?

```
demo
```

https://codepen.io/Turqus/pen/WXEryN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your service you were declaring this.whichBoard but inside the function you again used the same named variable. If you set this.board inside, it would probably work:

```
app.service('serwis', ()=> {
  this.whichBoard = (index) => {
    this.board = index;
  };
});
```

Also in the calling method, you have:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="passParameterToService($index)">
  <span ng-repeat="item in arrayIndex">{{item}}</span>
</a>
```

You're passing $index, which isn't a value. Also, you have the repeat inside the method call, so change it to:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in arrayIndex track by $index">
  <a href="#" ng-click="passParameterToService(item)">{{item}}</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey if I have variable in service, for example this.helloWorld = '', can I pass by ng-click value to this variable? for example ng-click="serwis.helloWorld = null" ??, It will work?

Comment: Not from the view to a service no. You have to go through the controller.

Comment: Ok last question, if I have serwis with variable this.hello = '';     and in controller I will make serwis.hello = 'yoYo'; this variable will be changed in service??

Comment: No, you'll need to have a method in the service to set a variable that you'll call from the controller.

Comment: so just only is one way to set variable in service its pass variable by function to service and there set it by method yes?:D

Comment: Yes, you can't access it from the template, so you have to go via the controller.